# Gauss-Bonnet theorem question

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-writing

I was wondering if someone here can give me a hand with the proof in the image below. This is not HW, just a brain-teaser I am working on.

[image]

Prove. $2\pi \chi(M)=\sum\limits_{v_i}k(v_i)$

Comment: The repeated use of $ k$ is confusing. So what are $j$ and $k$?

Answer (score 1):

The relevant fact is that the sum of the angles in a triangle equals $\pi.$ So, summing all the angles, you get $\pi$ times the number of triangles. But you ALSO get sum over the vertices of $-k(v)  2\pi$ (I am assuming the surface is closed for simplicity, the general case is the same). So, you get
$\pi T = -\sum k(v) + 2\pi V.$ Now, recall that in a triangulation, $E = 3/2 T,$ so the Euler characteristic is $V-E+T = V - 3/2 T + T = V - T/2.$

Compare the two formulas, and be enlightened.